# Creating view in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have started to work on Sencha touch a week ago and I still no able to figured out how to create a view. I want to create textfield and listView. Listview shold be shown below the textfield. I am able to show either ListView or textfield as I am able to extend only Ext.panel or Ext.List.

Please help. Please share a link those give details about creating views in Sencha touch.

```
Ext.define('TrainEnquiry.view.SearchTrains', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: "widget.searchtrains",
requires: [ 'Ext.dataview.List','Ext.form.FieldSet','TrainEnquiry.store.Homes'],
config: {
    title: 'Train Enquiry',
    items: [
         {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                style:'width:70%; margin:10px',
                padding: '10px',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        placeHolder: 'Username',
                        itemId: 'userNameTextField',
                        name: 'userNameTextField',
                        required: true
                    }
                ]
            },{ 
                        xtype: 'homepagelist',
                        style: 'margin-Top:100px',
                        config: {
                            itemTpl: '<div class="myContent">'+ 
                                    '<div><b>{status}</b> </div>' +
                                    '</div>',
                            store: 'Homes',

                            onItemDisclosure: true
                        }
                }
            ]
        }





});
```

Comment: I don't want to add it to application. I want to add it to TrainEnquiry.view.SearchTrains. How to add  this viewport to my view class. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The point of my example was that you need `layout: 'fit'` in your config for the `SearchTrains` view, which is a `panel` type. Also, to avoid overlapping, you probably want to dock the fieldset to the top with `docked: 'top'`.

Answer (score 3):

Showing `list` views when you are also using a containing element (like a `panel`) is one of the trickiest things in Sencha, in my opinion. It can be done, but you have to set the `layout: 'fit'` property on the panel. You'll also need to dock your fieldset to the top (assuming you want it at the top, and probably turn that simple `title` attribute into a `titlebar` view within the panel. Here's a link to a [SenchaFiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#x8rZo) demonstrating an example of how to do this, and some code for you below:

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
  xtype: 'panel',
  layout: 'fit',
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'titlebar',
      title: 'Train Enquiry',
      docked: 'top'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'fieldset',
      docked: 'top',
      items: [
        {
          xtype: 'textfield',
          placeHolder: 'Username',
          itemId: 'userNameTextField',
          name: 'userNameTextField',
          required: true
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      xtype: 'list',
      itemTpl: '<div class="myContent">'+ 
               '<div><b>{name}</b> </div>' +
               '</div>',
      data: [
        { name: 'Item 1' },
        { name: 'Item 2' },
        { name: 'Item 3' },
        { name: 'Item 4' }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

(By the way next time keep searching, this is the question/answer that most likely would have helped you most: [sencha don't seeing the list in a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412465/sencha-dont-seeing-the-list-in-a-panel/10412584#10412584))

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid using inline styling.
2. If you want the fieldset to stick to the top of the main panel always and the list to scroll, use `layout:'fit'` inside the main panel config and add `docked: 'top'` at the fieldset config.
3. If you want both of them to scroll, remove main panel layout (which will take `layout:'auto'`), put `scrollable:true` in main panel config and add `scrollable:false` in list config. Like this:

   ```
   config: {
     title: 'Train Enquiry',
     scrollable : true,
     items: [{
          xtype: 'fieldset',
          items: [{
             xtype: 'textfield',
             placeHolder: 'Username',
             itemId: 'userNameTextField',
             name: 'userNameTextField',
             required: true
          }]
        },{ 
             xtype: 'homepagelist',
             scrollable: false,   // no scrolling for the list
             config: {
                itemTpl: '<div class="myContent">'+ 
                         '<div><b>{status}</b> </div>' +
                         '</div>',
                store: 'Homes',
                onItemDisclosure: true
             }
          }]
      }
   ```

Get the code here: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#x8rZo#fRzwt